# Is there any formula for summation?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, self-learning

$$0.01\sum_{x=1}^{30}(0.99)^{x-1} = 1-0.99^{30}$$

I wonder if there is a formula for summation and I want to know. Would anyone mind telling me? It would be better for me to solve problems, like the above one.

([Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cej4.png))

Answer (score 5):

its [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}x^n=\frac{1-x^{d}}{1-x}$$

$$0.01\sum_{x=1}^{30}(0.99)^{x-1}=0.01\frac{1-0.99^{30}}{1-0.99}=1-0.99^{30}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula for summation as such. Each summation can be written in longhand i.e. the one in your question is equivalent to 
$$
\displaystyle 0.01(0.99^0+0.99^1+0.99^2+\cdots 0.99^{29})
$$
which is obviously the same as the RHS. Use the sum $S_n$ of the first $n$ terms of a geometric series with $a=1$ and $r=0.99$ to get
$$
\displaystyle 0.01\left(\frac{1(1-0.99^{30})}{1-0.99}\right)=0.01\left(\frac{1(1-0.99^{30})}{0.01}\right)=1-0.99^{30}.
$$